# How to start MediaPlayer after it has been stopped in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am new to Android and in my app I am working with `MediaPlayer`.

When I first tap the start button, the song plays, but when I tap the stop button and then I tap on the start button again, the song does not start playing again. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class PlayngUrlFiles extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start, pause, stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playingurls_layout);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3");
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.pause();
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592596/getting-illegalstateexception-in-mediaplayer-when-trying-to-getcurrentposition/34604404#34604404 hey you can try this .. it may help you

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: So many people tried to help. Better to mark if something solved your problem. Give an update on what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @@~ if(mp!=null){
}

Comment: when i stop my player and play again i am getting exceptions

Comment: Process: com.example.venkat.audiorecordingapp, PID: 2                                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateExcept                                                                       at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)

Comment: @AbhiRam after `mp.release()` you need to `mp.prepare()` for playing again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

for this solution, I took some info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13740850/3178454)

```
public class PlayngUrlFiles extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start, pause, stop;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    /**
     * remain false till media is not completed, inside OnCompletionListener make it true.
     */
    private boolean initialStage = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playingurls_layout);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (initialStage) {
                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    new Player()
                            .execute("http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3");
                } else {
                    if (mp && !mp.isPlaying())
                        mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp && mp.isPlaying())
                    mp.pause();
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
                    initialStage = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * preparing mediaplayer will take sometime to buffer the content so prepare it inside the background thread and starting it on UI thread.
     * @author piyush
     *
     */

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Boolean prepared;
            try {

                mp.setDataSource(params[0]);

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    initialStage = true;
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                }
            }); 
            mp.prepare();
            prepared = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;   
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                prepared = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progress.isShowing()) {
                progress.cancel();
            }
            Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
            mp.start();

            initialStage = false;
        }

        public Player() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(PlayngUrlFiles.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
            this.progress.show();

        }
    }

}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

in order to avoid data downloding, try this

```
public class PlayngUrlFiles extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start, pause, stop;
    boolean prepared;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playingurls_layout);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        prepared = false;

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                prepared = true;
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp) {
                    try {
                        if(!prepared) {
                            mp.prepareAsync();
                            prepared = true;
                        } else {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp) {
                    mp.pause();
                }
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp) {
                    mp.stop();
                    prepared = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @AbhiRam, please try to use the code I posted instead of yours and let me know if it works

Comment: wait ia m checking

Comment: please check ur code once and give correct solution

Comment: well, the problem is that you are fetching an mp3 from internet, for this reason it's not playing it, because it has still not be downloaded... I'll modify the code properly

Comment: u there ur providing solution?

Comment: yes, wait for it, please, it's not that simple indeed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117395/discussion-between-abhiram-and-ddb).

Comment: @AbhiRam, did you try my SOLUTION 2?

Comment: I didn't realize, your solution 1 should work, I added a slightly simple one though.

Answer (score 0):

just check like this way

```
if(mdpl.isPlaying()){
    mdpl.pause();
} else {
    mdpl.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call start, it media player in on stop state. Take a look on the state diagram of media player [MediaPlayer state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram).

When you call stop, you have to call release(), and with start you get a new media player, or just call reset.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onStopBtnClick(View view) {
    if (mAudioHelper != null) {
        mAudioHelper.stop();
        displayMessage("Stopping!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to set sound file.

```
if (mPlayer != null) {
     mPlayer.stop();
     mPlayer.release();
}
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AppLog.d("Created new Media player");
try {
     mPlayer.setDataSource(fileName);
} catch (IOException e) {
     AppLog.e("Can't open " + fileName + " file", e);
}
```

Before playing u should call the `mPlayer.prepareAsync()` function. 
if you want to pause/play you have to use this code:

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.pause();
} else {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

If you want to stop player use this:

```
if (mPlayer != null){
    mPlayer.stop();
    mPlayer.release();
}
mPlayer = null;
```

If you want to start song again use first functions and next with this steps

Comment: I am fully confused with ur code and very beginner in android please provide ur solution with editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you..

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        destroyMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void destroyMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {

                mediaPlayer.release();
                Log.d("here", "destroy");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@MRodrigues was right about media player states. But instead of calling release() after stop, Modify your code as below.

Currently,

```
try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3");
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

modify to,

```
try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.prepare();
                }
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```